How to send message in teams channel with @mention in.net 6 using webhook
How to send message in teams channel with @mention in.net 6 using webhook
    string userId = "xxxxx";  
    string userName = "xxxx";
    string userPrincipalname = "xxxx";

    var adaptiveCardPayload = new
    {
        type = "message",
        attachments = new[]
{
    new
    {
        contentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        content = new
        {
            type = "AdaptiveCard",
            version = "1.0",
            body = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    type = "TextBlock",
                    text = $"Hello <at>@{mentiontext}</at>, this is a message with an @mention!",
                    wrap = true
                }
            },
            mentions = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    mentioned = new
                    {
                        user = new
                        {
                            id = userId,
                            displayName = userName,
                            userPrincipalName = userPrincipalname
                        }
                    },
                    mentionText = $"@{mentiontext}",
                    id = userId
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    };

    var jsonPayload = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(adaptiveCardPayload);


    string responsess = await _connector.ExecutePostToMicroservice(uriBuilder.Uri, "Add new Team msg", jsonPayload, currentUserToken: CurrentUserToken);


Here I found a solution for mentioning the user in the Microsoft Teams channel using an incoming webhook.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cdesktop%2Cdesktop1%2Cdesktop2%2Cconnector-html#user-mention-in-incoming-webhook-with-adaptive-cards
